# Outputing to file and console in batch on windows

Tags: batch-file

I have this current code to start a irc bot

```
:1
lua5.1.exe bot.lua
GOTO :1
```

However I want everything that goes in to console to be printed to a log file so I did

```
:1
lua5.1.exe bot.lua > log.text
GOTO :1
```

And that worked fine however that makes it so nothing prints to console anymore, is there a way to change that?

I also would like a way to have the log.txt to be named something like %date%%time%.txt but when I do that, because of the way windows spits out the date it just names the file Fri(or what ever the day of the week happens to be) because it has a space, how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On linux/mac, use the tee command.

```
lua5.1.exe bot.lua | tee log.text | xargs echo
```

Comment: Thanks! What about the file name part though? Edit: This didnt work

Comment: Oh, you're on a windows host? I'm not sure if tee works in powershell. Couldn't tell you how to echo date on that os, either.

Comment: lua5.1.exe bot.lua | tee log.text | xargs echo
 runs the bot but it doesnt output to console, only the file